# What does an operator inside a bool query mean?

Tags: elasticsearch

Below is the example query. What does the operator in the `matches` mean? I couldn't find any documentation regarding this specific scenario.

```json
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "match": {
          "lastName": {
            "query": "John",
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "operator": "AND",
            "prefix_length": "1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "name": {
            "query": "John Doe",
            "operator": "OR"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "name.raw": {
            "query": "John Doe",
            "boost": 5.0,
            "operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "lastName": {
            "query": "Doe",
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "operator": "AND",
            "prefix_length": "1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#match-field-params) about the operator in Match Query.

Doc:

> operator (Optional, string) Boolean logic used to interpret text in
> the query value. Valid values are:
>
> OR (Default) For example, a query value of capital of Hungary is
> interpreted as capital OR of OR Hungary.
>
> AND For example, a query
> value of capital of Hungary is interpreted as capital AND of AND
> Hungary.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), `operator` is a

> Boolean logic used to interpret text in the `query` value.

In your example, your `query` is `John Doe`. With `AND` operator, the query will be interpreted as `John AND Doe`. While with `OR` operator (which is used by default), it would be `John OR Doe`.

`operator`s are used to express logical conditions in [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html). Please don't confuse it with *typed occurrences* in [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), which has 4 occurrences ("operator"): `must`, `filter`, `should`, and `must_not`.